# How to restore the charge of a floating gate?

Tags: flash

As commonly known the charge in a floating gate in a flash memory cell tends to leak over time. Some authors suggest rewriting of the cell to renew its charge. However, that reduces available resource.
Will the read operation on that cell refresh the charge?
Or maybe some other effective methods in maintaining flash memory in a well state are exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, reading will not refresh the cell. The parts have a limited number of writes; if you write too often, you will wear the part out.

For long life under severe conditions, some people recommend rewriting all the cells once every year or two. But, for most use, it is not necessary, the floating gate charge is likely to last longer than the useful life of your device.